# Poor laptop performance when moved to another location

Tags: laptop, performance, gpu

I first wanna say me and my friend both have this problem on different models of Asus ROG laptop.
We were in another city and were playing PUBG just normal. But when we moved to another city, we had this huge fps drop in game and i cant think of anything that can cause this issue. I’m using a laptop cooling pad as well. 
I think the problem might be the gpu not getting enough power or something like that but im using the same adapter.
When i launched the game on the first location the good fps was back.
Help me out here

Comment: PUBG is an online game, correct? Are you sure this isn't a network or Internet issue?

Comment: I dont think it is. I tried it with a wired network and my LTE and i didnt see much differ

Comment: Why do you assume both of your computers suddenly developed a problem rather than something related to the location change, like the service you're getting from the ISPs?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend that you write your computer specs in detail.

Secondly, are you sure you both did not run any background process at the other location you are describing?

From your description, the only thing I could imagine is that either you have had processes running in the background (antivirus, mail, update, whatever) which may affect your computer's performance. Or did the other location have a big difference in temperature? Were you in another country where the room temperature differs a lot causing the GPU to have lower cooling.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer , first my laptop model is g501vw with 960m gpu and my pal has an asus 980m gpu( i dont know the exact model). If the difference was a like 5 to 10 frames i would agree with u on that but i was getting like 50-70 fps there and now it’s less than 30. The temp is not much different.

Comment: Could you be more clear with your description of here and there, are you now receiving only 30 fps and before you were receiving 50-70? Or did you receive 50-70 at one location and then 30 fps at another location and now again 50-70 FPS? Because I do not believe your location matters, I would rather believe that either you have other processes running in the background, or your graphics card needs new drivers, maybe the game has updated and needs later version of your graphics drivers? Have you tried installing the newest drivers available and re-booting your pc?

Comment: @EmirHusic Of course location matters. If the internet connection to the game server is good at one place and bad at another it will have a big effect on the fps ...

Comment: I wanna run a benchmark on both locations and see if the gpu is the problem or something else

Comment: @DavidPostill - If the internet is a problem he could easily measure the response time between the two locations and the server. Also a measurement of the internet speeds.

Mohammad - Do you run through Wi-Fi or ethernet cable? If you are running Wi-Fi at a crowded place with poor connection it may result in connection dips.

Comment: Im using wifi but its not the problem and im the only user. I think if the internet was the problem it would get laggy but fps is consistantly low.

Comment: I agree with you on that, the internet should not affect your overall FPS. Check your background processes when running the game in order to free up ram memory and processes running in the background. So shut down any other applications running and only start the game and then try to compare if you keep getting fps drops (maybe try another game see if you get the same result?). If you do, I am not sure what could be the problem.